# Can the US embassy help a broke American citizen overstayed in the Emirates?

Tags: us-citizens, uae, emergencies, embassies

Can the US embassy send an American citizen home for free?

He's been sick for over a year and can't afford to go to the doctor or buy medicines, and has to take care of an 8 month old child. He's overstayed already by a year.

Comment: Is the 8 month old child also an American citizen?

Comment: birth cirtificate of his child they put filipino father they missed up

Comment: Why did this person wait a year past their allotted time to address this?

Comment: @StigTore uh, no - it is true that the country has to, under international law, admit their own citizens into their country, but there is no requirement for them to actually help their citizens travel to the border.  I have no idea where you get the idea that the US embassy *has* to help in this case, but its simply not true.  If the person in question arrived at a US border, they would be admitted - but thats it as far as legal obligations stand.

Comment: Not helpful in this case, sorry, but Travel Insurance is essential when travelling outside your own country or states (or eg EU citizen travelling outside EU).
I always ensure I have the insurance, not so much for lost property, but for medical and legal issues that might adversely affect me or my family.
Hope all goes well...

Comment: @xoxo If he is not on the birth certificate and if he has not adopted the baby, I have a hard time seeing how it is _his_ son in any way that is relevant to the authorities. Could you clarify if there is anything missing from the story?

Comment: You seem to be in a pretty harsh situation. You should contact the embassy. If you cannot contact the embassy, you should probably get in touch with a lawyer.

Comment: It would help to have information about the citizenship of the mother as well. OP seems to imply man in question is US citizen, and "taking care of" a child that is not officially his relative or ward. If so, embassy will assist the father but most likely will not overlook the fact he is requesting to bring a child that is not his along to the US. If nothing else, i would imagine he would have to prove he is authorized by the child's parent/guardian to take them across borders.

Comment: I'd have a hard time believing a one-year overstay was unforeseen or accidental. And the UAE fine for overstaying an employment visa jumps to AED50/day (after six months) then AED100/day (after one year). Also the child isn't either legally his or a US citizen (apparently), and none of us can tell the money was spent on medicine not fines. If he wants to apply for US citizenship for the child, why did they never get the birth cert corrected?

Answer (score 53):

> [**U.S. Embassy & Consulate in the United Arab Emirates Emergency Financial Assistance**](https://ae.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/emergency-financial-assistance/)
>
> U.S. consuls can assist U.S. citizens abroad who are temporarily destitute due to unforeseen circumstances.
>
> U.S. citizens in Abu Dhabi and Al Ain who find themselves in these circumstances should contact the Embassy in Abu Dhabi.  U.S. citizens in Dubai and other Emirates including southern Emirates should contact the Consulate in Dubai. You may also contact the State Department’s Office of Overseas Citizens Services at 1-888-407-4747 (during business hours) or 202-647-5225 (after hours).
>
> Consular officers can help destitute Americans contact family, bank, or employer to arrange for transfer of funds. In some cases, these funds can be wired through the Department of State. For information on how a consular officer can help under these circumstances, see [Emergency Financial Assistance for U.S. Citizens Abroad](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/emergencies/financial-assistance.html)
>
> Emergency Contact
>   P.O. Box 4009
>   Abu Dhabi, UAE
>   Phone: +971-2 414 2200

Answer (score 29):

Contact the US embassy. [Here](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/emergencies/financial-assistance.html) is a list of what they will do. They will give you a **loan** to travel home if there is no other source of money, and they will insist of getting repaid.

Comment: what do u think will gonna happen to him if he surrender to US EMBASSY AND TO HIS CHILD

Comment: He does not "surrender" to the US embassy. He asks about assistance. Surrendering would be to the Emirates immigration authorities. And if the child has the wrong father on the birth certificate, that needs to be sorted out first. Again the best bet is to talk to the embassy.

Comment: @xoxo the only reason to "surrender" to authorities of your own countries is if you're  fugitive of the law and are giving up your attempts to escape arrest. If that's the case here, he would certainly be brought back by the US government, in handcuffs and ankle chains, escorted by a pair of US Marshalls.

Comment: Is it really "will"? I read "can", and I see no promise of giving you a loan (merely assisting in contacting your bank, or in transferring money, etc). Also, I read "unanticipated", and something tells me the consulate/embassy will consider letting one year pass as not unanticipated.